# Proper way to put spring beans

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, spring-framework-beans

We are using java beans for dependency injection. However, we have found that the beans were not created in a proper way. My question is: what's a proper way to organize those beans? I have read many books or online posts about it but not clear about the solutions. Let me give you an example here. For example, I have a bean called `TestBeanA`and I put it in `moduleA`. I have another `moduleB` which references `moduleA`, so I can use `TestBeanA` in `moduleB`.

1)1st issue is: Now I have another `moduleC` which is in a different service or package. In order to use `TestBean` in`moduleC`, I can add `moduleA` as a dependency in `moduleC` then use `TestBean` there? Is this a good approach? or just create a new bean in `moduleC`?

2) 2nd issue is that: now if I have another bean `TestBeanB` in `moduleB`. How can i use this bean in `moduleA`? or putting `TestBean` in `moduleB` was wrong, and it should be put in `moduleA` as well?

Comment: You'd basically avoid circular dependencies like in your 2nd question. You need to move TestClassB to moduleA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each [bean](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html) holds logic or data that preferably isn't duplicated in your system, also most beans follow the singleton pattern, so it must be unique in the system

> When a bean is a singleton, only one shared instance of the bean will be managed

Thefore you should include module's bean in a new/updated module and not create redundant beans

Comment: Ok, what if we have a different case. If the the new/updated module(moduleB) needs a new bean, which is not in moduleA, is it better to create the new bean in moduleB or moduleA. I guess people will say it's case by case. But as a good practice,  should we put all beans in one configuration class, even different modules will need use them? Thank you!

Comment: @msProgram you should put bean when needed, it will prevent unnecessary dependencies between modules

Comment: Yes, the bean is needed. To prevent unnecessary dependencies between modules, we will put the bean in moduleB. But in case moduleA also needs it in the future, so it's better to put it in moduleA then.